# Find USA phone numbers in python script

Tags: python, regex

the following python script allows me to scrape email addresses from a given file using regular expressions.

How could I add to this so that I can also get phone numbers? Say, if it was either the 7 digit or 10 digit (with area code), and also account for parenthesis?

**My current script can be found below:**

```
# filename variables
filename = 'file.txt'
newfilename = 'result.txt'

# read the file
if os.path.exists(filename):
        data = open(filename,'r')
        bulkemails = data.read()
else:
        print "File not found."
        raise SystemExit

# regex = something@whatever.xxx
r = re.compile(r'(\b[\w.]+@+[\w.]+.+[\w.]\b)')
results = r.findall(bulkemails)
emails = ""
for x in results:
        emails += str(x)+"\n"

# function to write file
def writefile():
        f = open(newfilename, 'w')
        f.write(emails)
        f.close()
        print "File written."
```

Regex for phone numbers:

```
(\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4})
```

Another regex for phone numbers:

```
(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?
```

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302482/i-need-a-regular-expression-to-convert-us-tel-number-to-link

Comment: Do you have a regexp for phone numbers for us to critique?

Comment: I just added to my post what I have for phone numbers. Having difficult detecting 7 or 10 digit numbers that don't have a hyphens.

Comment: Just one "country"/system or world-wide? Do you need to distinguish between cell/mobile and landline? Do you need to distinguish special-purpose numbers like 800 numbers? Possible +<"country" code> prefix?

Comment: I was hoping to keep it relatively simple. So not worry about the country code. It should be able to accept area codes with or without the parenthesis. Or just plain 7 digit numbers too. There doesn't need to be a distinguish between numbers like 800 numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: You're right, it looks like someone posted something that should work. is there anyway that someone could describe how this works? I've posted it below the initial one above. How would I be able to add this to my regex for email addresses? Thanks again for the help

Comment: Brilliant. I'm working on an application and it needs to prevent people from sharing their phone numbers with each other. This works on a lot of different cases where users may try to be sneaky. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you are interested in learning Regex, you could take a stab at writing it yourself.  It's not quite as hard as it's made out to be.  Sites like [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) allow you to enter some test data, then write and test a Regular Expression against that data.  Using RegexPal, try adding some phone numbers in the various formats you expect to find them (with brackets, area codes, etc), grab a [Regex cheatsheet](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) and see how far you can get.  If nothing else, it will help in reading other peoples Expressions.

Edit:
Here is a modified version of your Regex, which should also match 7 and 10-digit phone numbers that lack any hyphens, spaces or dots.  I added question marks after the character classes (the []s), which makes anything within them optional.  I tested it in RegexPal, but as I'm still learning Regex, I'm not sure that it's perfect.  Give it a try.

```
(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})
```

It matched the following values in RegexPal:

```
000-000-0000
000 000 0000
000.000.0000

(000)000-0000
(000)000 0000
(000)000.0000
(000) 000-0000
(000) 000 0000
(000) 000.0000

000-0000
000 0000
000.0000

0000000
0000000000
(000)0000000
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found the RegexPal rather helpful. I added to my post and included what I have so far for phone numbers. Something I'm having difficulty doing is detecting 7 or 10 digit numbers that don't have any hyphens at all.

Comment: @Aaron, I took a shot at modifying the Regex you gave to solve your problem.  It's included in my answer, which I edited.  Give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: This looks really great. I just did some testing and appears to be working very well. My only question, how do implement this so that it can work with my existing email addresses? Is there a way to do this that isn't too much work? Thanks again

Comment: You should be able to implement it similarly to the way the email Regex is already implemented; Try modifying a copy of the `# regex = something@whatever.xxx` block.  I'd take a shot, but I've never touched Python before.  You simply want to search for matches to the phone number Regex within the file you open, and output them to `result.txt`.

Comment: Hey, what's the status on your project?  Did you get it implemented?

Comment: it matches non-latin characters ٠٧٧٠١٣٥٥٥٥

Comment: Use flag re.A if you are using python3 and want to avoid non-latin unicode

Comment: Given this is the first search result on Google, I think it's necessary to point out that there's now a [phonenumbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) module that can do this.

Comment: @Auguste how would I match emoji characters between numbers? say i have 123emoji345emoji4444, and would like to get 1233454444

Comment: I added additional condition for extra spaces around dashes. `r'(\(\d{3}\)\s*[-\.\s]\s*\d{3}\s*[-\.\s]??\s*\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})'`

Answer (score 27):

**This is the process of building a phone number scraping regex.**

First, we need to match an area code (3 digits), a trunk (3 digits), and an extension (4 digits):

```
reg = re.compile("\d{3}\d{3}\d{4}")
```

Now, we want to capture the matched phone number, so we add parenthesis around the parts that we're interested in capturing (all of it):

```
reg = re.compile("(\d{3}\d{3}\d{4})")
```

The area code, trunk, and extension might be separated by up to 3 characters that are not digits (such as the case when spaces are used along with the hyphen/dot delimiter):

```
reg = re.compile("(\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{4})")
```

Now, the phone number might actually start with a `(` character (if the area code is enclosed in parentheses):

```
reg = re.compile("(\(?\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{4}).*?")
```

Now that whole phone number is likely embedded in a bunch of other text:

```
reg = re.compile(".*?(\(?\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{4}).*?")
```

Now, that other text might include newlines:

```
reg = re.compile(".*?(\(?\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{4}).*?", re.S)
```

**Enjoy!**

I personally stop here, but if you really want to be sure that only spaces, hyphens, and dots are used as delimiters then you could try the following (untested):

```
reg = re.compile(".*?(\(?\d{3})? ?[\.-]? ?\d{3} ?[\.-]? ?\d{4}).*?", re.S)
```

Answer (score 8):

I think this regex is very simple for parsing phone numbers

```
re.findall("[(][\d]{3}[)][ ]?[\d]{3}-[\d]{4}", lines)
```

Answer (score 6):

Below is completion of the answers above. This regex is also able to detect country code:

```
((?:\+\d{2}[-\.\s]??|\d{4}[-\.\s]??)?(?:\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}))
```

It can detect the samples below:

```
000-000-0000
000 000 0000
000.000.0000

(000)000-0000
(000)000 0000
(000)000.0000
(000) 000-0000
(000) 000 0000
(000) 000.0000

000-0000
000 0000
000.0000
0000000
0000000000
(000)0000000

# Detect phone numbers with country code
+00 000 000 0000
+00.000.000.0000
+00-000-000-0000
+000000000000
0000 0000000000
0000-000-000-0000
00000000000000
+00 (000)000 0000
0000 (000)000-0000
0000(000)000-0000
```

**Updated as of 03.05.2022:**

I fixed some issues in the phone numbers detection regex above, you find it in the link below. Complete the regex to include more country codes.

https://regex101.com/r/6Qcrk1/1

Answer (score 3):

For spanish phone numbers I use this with quite success:

```
re.findall( r'[697]\d{1,2}.\d{2,3}.\d{2,3}.\d{0,2}',str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has posted this regex yet, I will. This is what I use to find phone numbers. It matches all regular phone number formats you see in the United States. I did not need this regex to match international numbers so I didn't make adjustments to regex for that purpose.

```
phone_number_regex_pattern = r"\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]\d{3}[-.\s]\d{4}"
```

Use this pattern if you want simple phone numbers with no characters in between to match. An example of this would be: "4441234567".

```
phone_number_regex_pattern = r"\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check : http://regex.inginf.units.it/. With some training data and target, it constructs you an appropriate regex. It is not always perfect (check F-score). Let's try it with 15 examples :

```
re.findall("\w\d \w\w \w\w \w\w \w\d|(?<=[^\d][^_][^_] )[^_]\d[^ ]\d[^ ][^ ]+|(?<= [^<]\w\w \w\w[^:]\w[^_][^ ][^,][^_] )(?: *[^<]\d+)+",  
           """Lorem ipsum ©  04-42-00-00-00 dolor 1901 sit amet, consectetur +33 (0)4 42 00 00 00 adipisicing elit. 2016 Sapiente dicta fugit fugiat hic 04 42 00 00 00 aliquam itaque 04.42.00.00.00 facere, 13205 number: 100 000 000 00013 soluta. 4 Totam id dolores!""")
```

returns `['04 42 00 00 00', '04.42.00.00.00', '04-42-00-00-00', '50498,']`
add more examples to gain precision

Comment: fails on simple "4441234567" number

Comment: The solution would be better with more examples (15 is too short)

Answer (score 0):

```
 //search phone number using regex in python

 //form the regex according to your output


 // with this you can get single mobile number



phoneRegex = re.compile(r"\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d")

Mobile = phoneRegex.search("my number is 123-456-6789")

print(Mobile.group())

Output: 123-456-6789


phoneRegex1 = re.compile(r"(\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d")

Mobile1 = phoneRegex1.search("my number is 123-456-6789")

print(Mobile1.group())

Output: 123-456-789


Mobile1 = phoneRegex1.search("my number is 456-6789")

print(Mobile1.group())

Output: 456-678
```

Comment: And what happens when there is no match? This: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` Rending the code all but useless.

Answer (score 0):

While these are simple solutions they are all incorrect for North America. The problem lies in the fact that area-code and exchange numbers cannot start with a zero or a one.

```
r"(\\(?[2-9]\d{2}\\)?[ -])?[2-9]\d{2}-\d{4}"
```

would be the correct way to parse a 7 or 10-digit phone number.
(202) 555-4111
(202)-555-4111
202-555-4111
555-4111
will all parse correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code to find the number like "416-676-4560"**

```
doc=browser.page_source
    phones=re.findall(r'[\d]{3}-[\d]{3}-[\d]{4}',doc)
```