# Django models -Best way to store multiple contact numbers

Tags: python, django

I'm a django developer, we have been working on 1.3. Now wanted to give a try to latest version i.e. 1.8.1. Since there are many changes from 1.3 to 1.8.1. Wanted to know is there any kind of `PhoneField` in Django which should store multiple phone numbers in one field. 
I was thinking of using JSON field for that purpose like

- Should support multiple numbers
- Should support "-" in the number
- Should support country codes like +XX
- Should support regx validation for phone number.

With JSON field I might be able to achieve that easily but validation would need separate functions.

```
contact_info = json.JSONField("ContactInfo", default=contact_default)
```

I found [this](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) but don't think much differ from Textfield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL you can use ArrayField.

```
contact_info = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=15), blank=True)
```

Official documentation here. [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)

Comment: Thanks for documentation which also gave me one another option  i.e  HStoreField

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that validates the numbers before being saved to the JSONField or HStoreField.

Example:

```
import re

def validate_phone_number(phone_number):
    valid_number_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})$')
    
    is_valid = re.match(valid_number_pattern, phone_number)

    return is_valid

def save_number(request):
    if request.METHOD == 'POST':
        phone_number = request.POST['number']
        is_valid = validate_phone_number(phone_number)
        if not is_valid:
            messages.error(request, 'Error, your phone number is not valid!')
            return redirect('main:add_number')
        else:
            [... Add the number(s) to the model's JSONField here ...]
            messages.success(request, 'Success!')
            return redirect('main:index')
```

Or, you can use a more complex regex from the selected correct answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3868861/3345051

Comment: Thank you for efforts. This was my last option. +1 for ready answer.