# extracting phone number using python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, extract

I am not getting expected results. Anyone pl check my code below and help

Expected result:

```
['(444)333-4444', '444-555-3424']
```

Actual result:

```
[('(444)333-4444', '(444)', '', '333', '-', '4444', '', '', ''), ('444-555-3424', '444', '-', '555', '-', '3424', '', '', '')]
```

Code:

```
tell_op = re.compile(r'''(
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?                # area code
    (\s|-|\.)?                        # separator
    (\d{3})                           # first 3 digits
    (\s|-|\.)                         # separator
    (\d{4})                           # last 4 digits
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?    # extension
    )''', re.VERBOSE)
oo = tell_op.findall('this is my phone number (444)333-4444, 444-555-3424')
print(oo)
```

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868753/find-phone-numbers-in-python-script

Comment: Your pattern could match more than the 2 examples and re.findall will return all the capturing groups, that is why you get those results. If you change the capturing groups into non capturing ones `(?:` you have your results. If that does not match all your requirements, could you update the question with examples that you do and do not want to match?

Answer (score 0):

please try below regex,it works for both inputs

```
mbl1='(444)333-4444'
mbl1='444-555-3424'

print(re.search(r'\d*\(*\d+\)*\d+\-\d+-*\d*',mbl1).group())
```

If you have another requirement,please let me know

Comment: Thanks SGR, but it is not working for me however I tried: re.compile(r'(\+?\(?\d{3}\)?[-.]?\d{3}?[-.]\d{4})')   it is working fine except '?' doesn't work with '\d'  for pattern like 333-4444 (means with less digits)

Comment: This regex is matching `1234567890123(((((((((((00-1----------------------`, not sure it's a valid phone number.

Comment: hey bro thanks.. i could achieve results with re.compile(r'(\+?\(?\d{2}\)?[-.\s]?\d{10}|\d{10})')... also in first code I shared I was helped by friend here, he told me to use non-capturing groups.. that also worked.. thanks a lot for your time.