# Appending a +1 to string of digits with re.sub

Tags: regex, python-3.x

How do I use the re.sub python method to append +1 to a phone number?

When I use the following function it changes this string "802-867-5309" to this string "+1+15309". I'm trying to get this string "+1-802-867-5309". The examples in the docs replace show how to replace the entire string I don't want to replace the entire string just append a +1

```
import re
def transform_record(record):
  new_record = re.sub("[0-9]+-","+1", record)
  return new_record

print(transform_record("Some sample text 802-867-5309 some more sample text here"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can match your phone numbers with a pattern you may refer to the match value using `\g<0>` backreference in the replacement.

So, taking the simplest pattern like `\d+-\d+-\d+` that matches your phone number, you may use

```
new_record = re.sub(r"\d+-\d+-\d+", r"+1-\g<0>", record)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cn6On0/1). See more ideas on how to match phone numbers  at [Find phone numbers in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868753/find-phone-numbers-in-python-script).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/nlnKIc):

```
import re
def transform_record(record):
  new_record = re.sub(r"\d+-\d+-\d+", r"+1-\g<0>", record)
  return new_record

print(transform_record("Some sample text 802-867-5309 some more sample text here"))
# => Some sample text +1-802-867-5309 some more sample text here
```

Comment: just wanna add a comment to the verified answer the regex should be r"\d+-\d+-?\d+", r"+1-\g<0>"
question mark nezt to the second dash , so that even if the number only have one dash like for instance 802-8675309 it will still print +1-802-867-5309 the final code is : new_record = re.sub(r"\d+-\d+-?\d+", r"+1-\g<0>", record)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
new_record = re.sub(r"\d+-[\d+-]+", r"+1-\g<0>", record)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).