# Google scrape returns no description or email

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a description and email from each of Google searches, but it returns only titles and links. I'm using Selenium to open pages and bs4 to scrape the actual content.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.
Thanks!

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
result_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'g'})


links = []
titles = []
descriptions = []
emails = []
phones = []

for r in result_div:
# Checks if each element is present, else, raise exception
    try:
    # link
        link = r.find('a', href=True)

    # title
        title = None
        title = r.find('h3')

        if isinstance(title,Tag):
            title = title.get_text()

    # desc
        description = None
        description = r.find('div', attrs={'class': 'IsZvec'})
        #description = r.find('span')
    

        if isinstance(description, Tag):
            description = description.get_text()
            print(description)
    # email

        email = r.find(text=re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]*'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue here is that the class names are dynamic, so you have to change your strategy and select your elements by `tag` or `id`.

```
...
data = []

for e in soup.select('div:has(> div > a h3)'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.h3.text,
        'url':e.a.get('href'),
        'desc':e.next_sibling.text,
        'email':m.group(0) if (m:= re.search(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', e.parent.text)) else None
    })
    
data
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'Email design at Stack Overflow',
  'url': 'https://stackoverflow.design/email/guidelines/getting-started/',
  'desc': 'An email design system that helps us work together to create consistently-designed, properly-rendered email for all Stack Overflow users.',
  'email': None},
 {'title': 'Is email from do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email legit? - Meta ...',
  'url': 'https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338332/is-email-from-do-not-replystackoverflow-email-legit',
  'desc': '23.11.2016 · 1\xa0AntwortYes it is legit. We use it to protect stackoverflow.com user cookies from third parties. The links in the email are all rewritten to a\xa0...',
  'email': 'do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email'},
 {'title': "Newest 'email' Questions - Stack Overflow",
  'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email',
  'desc': 'Use this tag for questions involving code to send or receive email messages. Posting to ask why the emails you send are marked as spam is off-topic for Stack\xa0...',
  'email': None},
 {'title': 'Contact information - contact us today - Stack Overflow',
  'url': 'https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact',
  'desc': "A private, secure home for your team's questions and answers. Perfect for teams of 10-500 members. No more digging through stale wikis and lost emails—give your\xa0...",
  'email': None},
 {'title': 'How can I get the email of a stackoverflow user? - Meta Stack ...',
  'url': 'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64970/how-can-i-get-the-email-of-a-stackoverflow-user',
  'desc': '18.09.2010 · 1\xa0AntwortYou can\'t. Read your own profile. The e-mail box says "never displayed". The closest we have to private messaging is commenting as a reply\xa0...',
  'email': None},...]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! But when I pasted your code, it throws invalid syntax at m:= re.search... Since I suck at bs4, could u help me a bit here, please?

Comment: Is your python version up to date? Else you have to use `'email': re.search(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', e.parent.text).group(0) if re.search(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', e.parent.text) else None` to check or use `try/except` before appending

Answer (score 0):

To scrape Google Search you can use only `Beautifulsoup` webscraping library without `selenium` webdriver that will increase the speed of the script.

To avoid blocks from Google, if using `requests`  could be to [rotate `user-agent`](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents), for example, to switch between PC, mobile, and tablet, as well as between browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and so on, as default `user-agent` in requests library is a [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) so the website can understand that it's a script that sends a request.

To collect the necessary information (email, description, title, number, etc.) you can use CSS selectors search which are easy to identify on the page using a [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension (*not always work perfectly if the website is rendered via JavaScript*).

```py
import requests, re, json, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

params = {
  'q': 'Facebook.com Dantist gmail.com',   # query
  'hl': 'en',                              # language
  'gl': 'us'                               # country of the search, US -> USA
}

html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search',
                    headers=headers,
                    params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

data = []

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
    title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
    link = result.find('a')['href']
    snippet = result.select_one('.lyLwlc').text
       
    match_email = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+', snippet)
    email = ''.join(match_email)

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/3868861/15164646
    match_phone = re.findall(r'((?:\+\d{2}[-\.\s]??|\d{4}[-\.\s]??)?(?:\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}))', snippet)
    phone = ''.join(match_phone)
    
    data.append({
        'Title': title,
        'Link': link,
        'Email': email if email else None,
        'Phone': phone if phone else None
    })

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "Title": "Island Dental Associates | Franklin Square NY - Facebook",
    "Link": "https://www.facebook.com/IslandDentalAssociates/",
    "Email": "islanddentalassociatesny@gmail.com",
    "Phone": "(516) 271-0585"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Dental Bright | Houston TX - Facebook",
    "Link": "https://www.facebook.com/DentalBrightHouston/",
    "Email": "Dentalbrighttx@gmail.com",
    "Phone": "(713) 783-6060"
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, json, re

params = {
   "engine": "google",                         # search engine. Google, Bing, Yahoo, Naver, Baidu...
   "q": "Facebook.com Dantist gmail.com",      # search query
   "api_key": os.getenv('API_KEY')             # your serpapi api key
}
 
search = GoogleSearch(params)                  # where data extraction happens
results = search.get_dict()                    # JSON -> Python dictionary

data = []

for result in results['organic_results']:
   title = result['title']
   link = result['link']
   snippet = result['snippet']

   match_email = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+', snippet)
   email = '\n'.join(match_email)

   match_phone = re.findall(r'((?:\+\d{2}[-\.\s]??|\d{4}[-\.\s]??)?(?:\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}))', snippet)
   phone = ''.join(match_phone)

   data.append({
     'title': title,
     'link': link,
     'email': email if email else None,
     'phone': phone if phone else None
   })

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```
The answer is identical to the answer bs4.
```