# Finding a valid phone number and wrapping it in an anchor tag (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are some similar questions out there, but I haven't been able to successfully adapt the code I've seen from [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661408/jquery-how-to-wrap-regex-matched-plain-text-in-an-anchor-tag) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309763/jquery-selector-contains-use-regular-expressions).

Perhaps the big difference is that I'm not trying to search actual text nodes in the DOM, but I am storing strings in an object. I have a `listings` object which I am populating with data from a classified listings API. So I want to take each `listings[i].body` property, use a regular expression to find any telephone numbers, and then wrap them with `<a href="tel:x">`. This same data will then be used to populate Google Maps Markers and Info Windows.

Comment: is your code confidential!you need to show us the code you have tried..

Comment: You also haven't asked a question… :)

Comment: This is a question I asked for C#, but you should be able to easily translate it to JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302482/i-need-a-regular-expression-to-convert-us-tel-number-to-link

Comment: Thanks @BoltBait, I hadn't come across your question because I was filtering by "JavaScript," but the solution to your question helped me out!

Comment: Solution: iterate through `listings`, then for each listing, `listing.body = listing.body.replace(/(\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4})\b/g, "<a href='tel:$1'>$1</a>");`

Comment: Edit your original post and update it with code instead of pasting it in the comments.